# python dict creation efficiency (`fromkeys`/`update`)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to programmatically create a `fields` dict for a `pymongo.Collection.find` call. The dict's keys are field names, vals are `1` if the field should be included, `0` if it should be excluded. Given two lists--`fields` and `omit_fields`, which is more efficient:

```
fields = dict.fromkeys(fields, 1)
unwanted_fields = dict.fromkeys(omit_fields, 0)
wanted_fields.update(unwanted_fields)
```

or

```
fields = dict.fromkeys(fields, 1)
for field in omit_fields:
    fields[field] = 0
```

or is there some other better way?

Comment: I recommend using `timeit` to measure the performance of each.